# SwiftUI white space under the NavigationBar

Tags: swift, swiftui, background-color, navigationbar

I have a view with a NavigationBar with a large title and content inside. I've changed the content background color and the NavigationBar background color.

```
 var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
            VStack {
               //content
            }.background(Color.green)
             .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom) //to fill the white space at the bottom
             .navigationBarTitle("Wallets")
       }
}
```

```
extension UINavigationController {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let standartAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()       
        standartAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        navigationBar.standardAppearance = standartAppearance
        navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = standartAppearance
        navigationBar.compactAppearance = standartAppearance
    }
}
```

And now if I move to the next view using the NavigationLink, and this view has a title with .inline display mode (different NavigationBar size), in the moment of the transition I see the white space under the first Navigation bar. I can fill it if I make .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) for my VStack, but in this case all my content jump under the NavigationBar. How can I color the space under the NavigationBar to custom color?

Comment: Do you succeed to fix it ?

Comment: I didn't find a normal solution, see the workaround below.

Comment: Yeah great. I'm fixing it with offset !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug. I didn't find the normal solution. Here is a workaround:

We should calculate the NavigationBar heigh and fill the space behind it.

```
var deviceHeight: CGFloat {
    UIScreen.main.bounds.height
}

  func calcPadding() -> CGFloat {
        var padding: CGFloat = 0.0
        switch self.deviceHeight {
        case 568.0: padding = 94.0 + 6.0
        case 667.0: padding = 96.0 + 10.0
        case 736.0: padding = 96.0 + 10.0
        case 812.0: padding = 106.0 + 10.0
        case 896.0: padding = 106.0 + 10.0
        default:
            padding = 106.0
        }

    return padding
}


var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                 //content
            }
            .padding(.top, calcPadding())
            .background(Color.myBackground)
        }
        .background(Color.myBackground)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: what about when you rotate the phone to Landscape ?  The heights do no longer apply then, no? Isn't there a better solution to this problem ?